# What is Ring basis?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I'm wondering what ring basis is.
Suppose we have a ring $R$, what basis does?
For example, suppose we have a cyclotomic ring $R'$, the ring basis is defined as
$\{1,\zeta,\ldots, \zeta^{n-1}\}$ where $\zeta$ is a m-th primitive root of unity and $n$ is its degree.

Comment: I've never heard of a "ring basis" before.  I think in the example you've given, we're considering $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, and you've given a basis in that sense.  In general, a field extension $K$ of a field $F$ is always an $F$-vector space.

Comment: The example you mention only works if $n$ is prime (and if you drop the $1$), otherwise, if $n$ is composite the basis is formed of the $\zeta^k$ where $k$  is coprime to $n$.

Answer (score 2):

An [integral basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_field#Integral_basis) for a number ring (a ring of algebraic integers) is a set of numbers such that every element in the ring is a linear combination of elements of the basis with *integer coefficients*.

A basis like the one you mention in the question is called a [power basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_field#Power_basis).

Answer (score 0):

In some situations a ring can have a basis even without being a field. When the ring can be considered as an algebra then the notion basis makes sense. For example the ring $\Bbb Q[x,y]/(x^2+xy+y^2-x-y-2, y^3-y^2-2y+1)$ has as a basis $1, x, x^2, y, xy, x^2y$. It is not a field  since with $q_1 = xy-x+1$ and $q_2 = -x^2-2*x*y+y$  we have that $q_1q_2 = (-xy-y^2+x)(x^2+x*y+y^2-x-y-2) + (2x+y)(y^3-y^2-2y+1)$ so the ring has zero divisors and is not a field.

Comment: You should probably add what sort of a basis this is. It is not an independent generating set for the ring as a ring for example.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: You are right, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: A couple of further things: It is important what it is an algebra over (all rings are algebras over the integers for example). The existence of a basis over whatever ring it is an algebra over is practically unrelated to whether the ring itself is a field, so I am not sure why you mention it.

Comment: Because a comment gave the impression that bases only existed in the framework of algebraic extensions ( so fields).  But what do you do when the dimension is not finite?

Comment: The same as always. Modules over fields have bases, hence algebras over fields do (as this part ignores the multiplication).